# How to skip to copy Read only Directories in C#

Tags: c#, exception, copy, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I trying to write a code that will copy all files from give directory and its all sub directories.  (Only copy files not directories).

This is so far i have

```
public static void Copy(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);        
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)),true);

    foreach(var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
        Copy(directory, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
}
```

I am facing two problems here.

1. I get unauthorized Access exception. There is a folder in source directory that is creating problem.

   - [image]

2nd problem is. If it copies it copy all files and folder as it is in the source directory. but I only need files.

Any solution for both problems ?

Comment: Its not that its read only - its because you dont have access. If you catch that exception, and exit the function it will skip it because you cant see it. If you dont need it to recursively do subdirectories, you dont need the second part anyway - or do you mean you wish to flatten the whole thing so all files are in one big folder?

Comment: Try to run as an admin.

Comment: @BugFinder I want to copy files of sub directories. But dont need directories itself. 
Yeah  I wish to flatten the whole thing so all files are in one big folder

Answer (score 1):

OK to copy all sub directories, and so on, omitting any that wont let you have access:

Before you call copy, you would need to check targetDir exists.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(targetDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);
```

you should really check it can do that etc, then to recursively copy the folders into the same one:

```
public static void Copy(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
{
  try
  {
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    try 
      {  File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)),true);}  
      catch {} // you could do other things to handle different issues - like lack of space, etc

    foreach(var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
        Copy(directory, targetDir)); // this will go into each subdirectory, and do the same.
   }
   catch {} // catches unable to access directory you've gone into
 }
```

}

You keep the final destination the same if you wanted a flat dump into a folder, by trying to append the path etc to copy you were recreating the whole directory structure.

Comment: Still  same exception at first foreach :(

Comment: Yes, I changed my mind on where I'd put it, but yes, if you have no access then it would.. 1 sec - although Id have thought you would be able to get the idea..

Comment: Actually now we are just catching exceptions. But good thing is I am able to copy all files without folder. I am not sure if it will still copy or not. I am voting ur answer up. When I am sure about it. I will accept as answer :)

Comment: You are the one in control of your code - you catch exceptions because they can happen, the overall one catches if you cant do squat with the folder.. the one on copy handles specific file issues and will copy "all it can" out of the folder.. (and handles if the file goes missing since it got the list), it then goes on and goes into each sub folder.. its your code, you should be in control of it.

Comment: But still here is a problem. If a folder causes exception. then code will go to catch. it means program execution will be stopped. And remaining files will be skipped from copying. Any solution for that ?

Comment: No, it doesnt stop - thats the point of recursion, only that tree stops.. the rest of the tress continue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87453/discussion-between-adnan-ali-and-bugfinder).

Comment: The exception in in Directory.GetDirectories() will cause it to terminate prematurely, and no amount of catching will fix it.

Comment: It does if you have the try before the "Directroy.GetDirectories" .. because it absorbs it and exits, therefore it doesnt terminate, it just terminates that tree because you cant do it.  I use code just like this every day in looking for files people have moved by accident

Comment: Ah yes, you're handling the recursion yourself - that will work. (It fails if you use the call of GetDirectories() which does its own recursion, but you're not doing that)